Cannot run sample flask app in Kubernetes - could not import index error
I am trying to run sample Flask app in kubernetes.
I've done the required changes and tried in local linux VM. i can see flask app is running successfully inside a container.
But when I deploy the same image in kubernetes getting below error.
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not import 'index'.

Below is my Dockerfile
FROM <python3 base image>


RUN mkdir -p /workdir/app



WORKDIR /workdir/app

COPY . .

RUN  pip3 install --requirement requirements.txt


ENV FLASK_APP=src/index.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_ENV=development

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["flask", "run"]

My folder structure
Dockerfile
src/index.py
src/healthcheck
requirements.txt

My index.py file
# Importing flask module in the project is mandatory
# An object of Flask class is our WSGI application.
from flask import Flask

from healthcheck import bp as healthcheck_bp

# Flask constructor takes the name of
# current module (__name__) as argument.
app = Flask(__name__)


app.register_blueprint(healthcheck_bp, url_prefix="/healthcheck")


@app.after_request
def remove_server_header(response):
    app.logger.info(response.headers)
    # response.headers["Server"]
    return response


# main driver function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, passthrough_errors=True, use_debugger=False, use_reloader=False)

If I run the docker image in local I don't see any errors. But when I deploy in kubernetes namespace getting mentioned error.
Am I missing something here?

I'm unable to repro your issue. Your code (without healthchecking for which you provide no implementation) works for me locally and, when deployed to Kubernetes. Please update your question to be a minimal repro, add the details of how you run/tested locally and to Kubernetes.

Is the file named src/healthcheck or src/healthcheck.py? If the former, the import statement would never work. Please update your question with a [mcve] -- code that we can run to reproduce the problem.
